# Building overlapping, oddly-rotated sprites

Tags: html, css, image, sprite, css-sprites

My current project involves setting up a bunch of sidebar links, such that the finished design looks like this:
[image: Finished design.]

The envelopes are supposed to move and overlap (i.e., change z-index), depending upon which icon/text is currently has :hover state.

I thought each would be a separate PNG file, but I've been given a sprite that looks like this:
[image: Sprite]

Any suggestions how I could achieve this? Normally I'd just change the background position of the list elements each piece of text is in, but I don't think this is possible given the overlapping nature of these. Does he just need to export it differently?

Many thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me it looks like that sprite would work perfectly. The left most image is for when book is hovered, second image for twitter, third for facebook, forth for email. I'm guessing the last one is just the default state. Its tricky to make this work with pure css and :hover (but possible!), however, it would be extremely easy with javascript.

For the pure css solution, the div with the sprite would have to be the child of all the text elements, so you could change the background based on :hover on the parent (the text). If this isn't clear, I can make you some example code.

#### Edit:

Its not perfect, but its a proof of concept.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jp6fy/

CSS:

```
#side{
    position:relitive;
    height:341px;
    width:250px;
}

#link1{
    top:0;
}

.link{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:85px;
    height:85px;
    padding-left:160px;
    width:90px;
}

#image{
    position:absolute;
    top:-255px;
    left:0;
    z-index:-1;
    background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2Y4k.png) -720px 0;
    height:341px;
    width:150px;
}

#link1:hover #image{
    background-position:-540px 0;
}

#link2:hover #image{
    background-position:-360px 0;
}

#link3:hover #image{
    background-position:-180px 0;
}

#link4:hover #image{
    background-position:-0px 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='side'>
    <div class='link' id='link1'>
        email
        <div class='link' id='link2'>
            facebook
            <div class='link' id='link3'>
                twitter
                <div class='link' id='link4'>
                    book
                    <div id='image'></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the pure-CSS version? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Edited answer to include example code. Its not pretty, but it works.

Comment: Not pretty, but excellent implementation for a pretty tough problem, +1.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. (But ugly.)

As a `:hover` selector can only affect elements inside (or directly adjacent) to the triggering element, the solution is to nest the trigger elements: [(jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/2NbaU/)

```
<style>
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
}
#image { background: black; }
#trigger1, #trigger1:hover #image { background: red; }
#trigger2, #trigger2:hover #image { background: green; }
#trigger3, #trigger3:hover #image { background: blue; }
</style>

<div id="trigger1">
  <div id="trigger2">
    <div id="trigger3">
      <div id="image"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But preferably, you'd get the envelope sprites exported separately (you can of course still use CSS sprites). That should give you simpler HTML and CSS, a smaller image, and you'll avoid having to muck around with nested absolutely positioned elements, each having its own coordinate system.

Answer (score 1):

I tried an approach which keeps the markup fairly simple, with only one extra non-semantic div per item:

```
<ul>
    <li id="email">
        <div class="background"></div>
        <em>Email</em> chris
    </li>
    <li id="facebook">
        <div class="background"></div>
        <em>Facebook</em> follow us
    </li>
    <li id="twitter">
        <div class="background"></div>
        <em>Twitter</em> your life away
    </li>
    <li id="book">
        <div class="background">
        </div><em>Book</em> a project
    </li>
</ul>
```

I positioned all the different copies of the background div at the same place, then varied the background position based on the hover states:

```
/* First, just style the document and the list text in general. 
   skip on for the important bit */
body {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
ul {
    width: 350px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    position: relative;
}
li {
    margin-right: 40px;
    font-family: "Century Gothic", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: right;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 15px 4px 25px 0;
}
li em {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
}
li:hover {
    color: red;
}

/* From here down is the important bit */

/* Set up the sprite in all the .background divs */
div.background { 
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2Y4k.png); 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 341px;
    width: 160px;
}

/* By default, turn off the background in all the divs */
div.background {
    display: none;
}

/* Just picking an arbitrary item to show the default, non-hover background */
#email div.background  {
    display: block;
    background-position-x: -737px;
}

/* If we're hovering over the list as a whole, disable the default background,
   so it doesn't show up underneath the background we want to display */
ul:hover #email div.background {
    display: none;
}

/* For the email item, which shows our arbitrary default background, override
   to the email background on hover with more specificity than the default rule */
ul:hover #email:hover div.background {
    display: block;
    background-position-x: 0px;
}

/* For all other items, override to their background on hover */
#facebook:hover div.background {
    display: block;
    background-position-x: -375px;    
}

#twitter:hover div.background {
    display: block;
    background-position-x: -189px;

}

#book:hover div.background {
    display: block;
    background-position-x: -556px;    
}
```

[Working, though slightly rough **example, in this jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gothick/qZWLB/4/).

Note that it's okay to have multiple copies of the sprite in multiple different divs; the browser will just grab one copy for its cache and use that for all instances of the image.

Comment: It would seem that this doesn't work in this case. Because the image is (supposed to be) transparent, the default sprite will be visible beneath the "hover" sprites.

Comment: @Søren I have made a quick fix. I now remove the default background when the pointer is hovering over the list as a whole, so that only the list item being hovered over has its background displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Could you create an image map and then hover swaps the image to the one with the correct envelope in front. See this link on an interesting link

[google search link on idea](http://www.tankedup-imaging.com/css_dev/rollover.html)

Answer (score 0):

My method with clean HTML.

```css
.nav { position: relative; }

.nav li {
  margin-left: 179.8px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav li:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  content: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2Y4k.png);
  clip: rect(0 899px 341px 719.2px);
  margin-left: -719.2px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav li:hover:before { z-index: 2; }

.email:hover:before {
  clip: rect(0 179.8px 341px 0);
  margin-left: 0;
}

.facebook:hover:before {
  clip: rect(0 359.6px 341px 179.8px);
  margin-left: -179.8px;
}

.twitter:hover:before {
  clip: rect(0 539.4px 341px 359.6px);
  margin-left: -359.6px;
}

.book:hover:before {
  clip: rect(0 719.2px 341px 539.4px);
  margin-left: -539.4px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="email">Email</li>
  <li class="facebook">Facebook</li>
  <li class="twitter">Twitter</li>
  <li class="book">Book</li>
</ul>
```